# Back and forth and the axiom of choice

Tags: model-theory, axiom-of-choice

Is the axiom of choice a *necessary* condition for the application of "back and forth construction" in model theory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As with many other things, the axiom of choice is not needed if the domain of discourse is well-ordered. So for example, without the axiom of choice countable atomless Boolean algebra still has a unique model.

The generality of the question, however, seem to imply the answer is yes. You make a lot of choices, and since you haven't put any limitations on the size of the models, or otherwise, then the answer is yes.