# Show that these two structures are isomorphic

Tags: logic, model-theory

I'm having difficulty knowing where to start with this question:

Show that:

($\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$,<)$\cong$($\mathbb{Q}$,<)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method , look at the application for dense linear orders.

Comment: Also you may want to look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2940700/let-p-q-prec-be-countable-dense-and-linearly-ordered-sets-without-end/2940728

Comment: And does the back and forth method show that these are isomorphic?

Comment: Yes. You have to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a dense countable linearly ordered set tho.